# Merge rows with the same name using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, zoho

Sorry, if this is a dumb question, but I have a table of months and I'm having trouble merging them.

This is what I have so far, which just selects and displays all of the dates in the table:

```
 SELECT absmonth( i."Date") "IsdMen"
 FROM "table_isd" i
```

So, for example, my Date row contains info like this:

```
2019-06-12
2019-07-12
2019-07-13
2019-07-14
2019-08-12
2019-08-13
```

And I want my MYSQL table to look like this:

```
2019-06
2019-07
2019-08
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m') IsdMen
FROM table_isd;
```

Your main requirement seems to be *presenting* your date values in the year-month format, and the `DATE_FORMAT` function was designed for this.

Comment: not really, my main requirement is merging all the dates with the same month into just one thing

Comment: Then use `SELECT DISTINCT`.